# Pictures in boxes with rounded corners

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using the tcolorbox LaTeX package to create some boxes with rounded corners. Everything works well when text goes in those boxes.

But I want to fill some of those boxes with just a picture (usually jpg format). Using \includegraphics inside the box indeed puts the picture in the box, but the rectangular picture does not have the rounded corners that I want. In other words, I want the corners of the picture to become rounded and not spill outside the box with rounded corners.

I would be grateful if someone can let me know how to do this. It would be nice to do so in tcolorbox, but I am also open to other solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with a minimal working example (MWE) showing how you are including an image right now. You can use one of the standard images e.g. `example-image-a` or whatever from the `mwe` package to enable people to reproduce your framework easily. (You don't need to load the package - you can just use the images in it straight off.) Generally, though, you'll need to mask or clip the image using something like TikZ or `pgfimage` or another package with similar functionality. Depending on your configuration, you may be using something like this in `tcolorbox` already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `tcolorbox` is implemented using `tikz`, this is actually simpler.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
\path[clip,draw,rounded corners=1.5cm] (0,0) rectangle (\wd0,\ht0);
\path (0.5\wd0,0.5\ht0) node[inner sep=0pt]{\usebox0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: That's a wonderful solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: How can i remove the black path that is drawn around the image?

Comment: The black edge is actually part of the image itself.  You would have to make the rectangle smaller to remove the edges.

Answer (score 12):

`watermark graphics` is a `tcolorbox` option which uses graphics file as box background. If no text is desired inside upper or lower parts, `height` option fixes box size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, watermark graphics=frog, watermark overzoom=1.0, title=example]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, watermark graphics=frog, watermark overzoom=1.0, notitle, height=5cm]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option could be to use `clip upper` option, which adjust upper part to interior size and form. In this case `\includegraphics` command forms the upper part. Following code is copied from page 166 in `tcolorbox` (v3.90) documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][]{%
\tcbox[enhanced,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,
right=0pt,boxrule=0.4pt,drop fuzzy shadow,clip upper,
colback=black!75!white,toptitle=2pt,bottomtitle=2pt,nobeforeafter,
center title,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,title=\detokenize{#2}]
{\includegraphics[width=\the\dimexpr(\linewidth-4mm)/2\relax]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\mygraphics{frog}
\mygraphics{lion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**update** `tcolorbox` more recent versions include command `tcbincludegraphics` which combines an `includegraphics` command inside a `tcolorbox`. Therefore previous examples can be simplified. More information can be found in section *11 Inclusion of Boxed Image Files*. Here you have some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{colframe=red!70!black, 
    size=tight, boxrule=1mm, arc=2mm, auto outer arc,
    nobeforeafter}
\begin{document}
\tcbincludegraphics{frog}

\tcbincludegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, graphics options={width=3cm}]{frog}
%
\tcbincludegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, hbox, graphics options={width=3cm}]{frog}
\end{document}
```

[image]